# Typgraphy - hanging punctuation (indent list or not for better readablity)

Tags: lists, typography

In a body of text that contains both paragraphs and ordered and unordered list. Does it matter to indent the list items - by default, most browsers indent list items 16px?

The list in the following image is not indented. The bullets are at the same point on x-axes as the paragraph.

[image]

However, the list is indened 16px in this one.

[image]

Comment: Many web conventions for text display are adaptations of conventions for printed matter. It may be worthwhile to research whether (and why) the indentation convention exists for printed material.

Comment: This question may be better suited to the graphic design stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think there is a hard and fast rule for this, indentation breaks the flow so that it draws attention and users can quickly scan it and notice that there is a list. Used correctly, lists are very important because they mean that there are a number of items that need attention.

[From NN/G](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/presenting-bulleted-lists/)

> Bulleted lists attract attention, support scanning, shorten text, and
> reveal the relationship of items.
> Many different web-formatting techniques help break up dense
> paragraphs. Along with bolding, **indenting**, line spacing, and
> color-coding, bulleted lists are one of the most powerful methods for
> supporting efficient reading on the web.

However, I think the most important thing is to make sure you have consistent styling. Whatever indentation style you choose, make sure it's applied throughout the application.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Consistent_list_indentation)

> In the end, we can see that none of the browsers mentioned in this
> article is right or wrong about how they lay out lists. They use
> different default styles, and that's where the problems creep in. By
> making sure you style both the left padding and left margin of lists,
> you can find much greater cross-browser consistency in your list
> indentation.

​I personally find your first example (without indentation) much difficult to read. Also, I did a quick check of several well-known websites, and they all use indentation, so I assume this is an accepted pattern.